# npm find-babel-config depends on a vulnerable version of JSON5

Tags: npm, expo, babeljs

The package manager npm gives a high severity vulnerability which I don't know how to fix. The advised forced fix wants to install a very old version of expo. Node is up to date (v18.14.1). There seems to be an outdated version reference in 'find-babel-config' to JSON5.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this dependency? I tried reinstalling and updating npm, including manually deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, cleaning npm cache and updating expo.

```
npm audit
```

```
# npm audit report

json5  <1.0.2
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in JSON5 via Parse Method - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9c47-m6qq-7p4h
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@1.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/babel-preset-expo/node_modules/json5
  find-babel-config  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of json5
  node_modules/babel-preset-expo/node_modules/find-babel-config
    babel-plugin-module-resolver  2.3.0 - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of find-babel-config
    node_modules/babel-preset-expo/node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver
      babel-preset-expo  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-module-resolver
      node_modules/babel-preset-expo
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-preset-expo
        node_modules/expo
```

Comment: npm start -- --reset-cache allowed me to install libraries (such as createBottomTabNavigator) that was not possible before, but the vulnerabilities are still there...

Answer (score 1):

In your package-lock.json file you should be able to find what it's a dependency on. In my case it was babel-plugin-module-resolver which I upgraded to 5.0.0 to resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).